# What is the physical difference between the Subsurface Scattering and Translucent shaders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, subsurface-scattering

Generally speaking, I know to use translucent for leaves and SSS for skin, but why is this? Physically speaking, how do these shaders refract/scatter rays differently? Why does translucent have no sliders or options? If anyone could sketch up some rough optical diagrams, that would be absolutely awesome! Any responses are appreciated :)

Comment: If i remember correctly, the translucent is like a really lite version of the SSS. Same basic principle, vastly lower quality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Translucency allows light to pass through an object. Using only a translucent shader will leave an object dark on the side receiving light with the other sides being lit.

[image: translucent sample]

Sub Surface Scattering allows light to penetrate the surface and be distorted before bouncing back out. Each colour component [disperses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)) differently, leaving areas with a different colour than others. Thin areas allow light to pass through to light the opposite side before being bounced back out, these thin areas give a translucent appearance.

[image: SSS sample]